# Decrease time until onPressAndHold is emitted on ItemDelegate

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I have the following example Qt Quick application:

```js
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    ListView {
        id: list
        anchors.fill: parent

        model: ListModel {
            id: listView
            ListElement { name: "Element 1" }
            ListElement { name: "Element 2" }
            ListElement { name: "Element 3" }
            ListElement { name: "Element 4" }
        }

        delegate: ItemDelegate {

            property string textcolor: "black";
            contentItem: Text {
                id: content
                width: parent.width
                text: name
                color: textcolor
            }

            onPressAndHold: { textcolor = "red"; }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm changing the text color on a single element trough the `onPressAndHold` event. How can I decrease the duration until the event is emited?
I tried to use pressAndHoldInterval but it seems like it does not exist for [ItemDelegate](http://pressAndHoldInterval).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interval is established through the `mousePressAndHoldInterval()` of `QStyleHints`, in this case the solution is to use the setter that seems to be undocumented.

```cpp
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
app.styleHints()->setMousePressAndHoldInterval(10);
```

Comment: This works like a charm! I was looking for a solution in QML and never thought about setting it globally.